# php/dos : How do you parse a regedit export file?

Tags: php, regex, registry, regedit

My objective is to look for Company key-value in the registry hive and then pull the corresponding Guid and other keys and values following it.  So I figured i would run the regedit export command and then parse the file with php for the keys I need.

So after running the dos batch command

```
>regedit /E "output.txt" "HKLM\System....\Company1"
```

The output textfile seems to be in some kind of UNICODE format which isn't regex friendly.     I'm using php to parse the file and pull the keys.

Here is the php code i'm using to parse the file

```
<?php 

$regfile = "output.txt";


$handle = fopen ("c:\\\\" . $regfile,"r");
//echo "handle: " . $file . "<br>";
$row = 1;


while ((($data = fgets($handle, 1024)) !== FALSE) ) {

    $num = count($data);
    echo "$num fields in line $row: \n";

$reg_section = $data;   
//$reg_section = "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TECHNOLOGIES\MEDIUS\CONFIG MANAGER\SYSTEM\COMPANIES\RECORD11]";

$pattern = "/^(\[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\\SOFTWARE\\\TECHNOLOGIES\\\MEDIUS\\\CONFIG MANAGER\\\SYSTEM\\\COMPANIES\\\RECORD(\d+)\])$/";
if ( preg_match($pattern, $reg_section )) { 

echo "<font color=red>Found</font><br>"; 

} else { 
echo "not found<br>"; 
echo $data . "<br>";
}
$row++;
} //end while 
fclose($handle);


?>
```

and the output looks like this....

> 1 fields in line 1: not found
>   ÿþW�i�n�d�o�w�s� �R�e�g�i�s�t�r�y�
>   �E�d�i�t�o�r� �V�e�r�s�i�o�n�
>   �5�.�0�0� � 1 fields in line 2: not
>   found
>
> 1 fields in line 3: not found
>   [�H�K�E�Y�*�L�O�C�A�L�*�M�A�C�H�I�N�E�\�S�O�F�T�W�A�R�E�\�I�N�T�E�R�S�T�A�R�
>   �T�E�C�H�N�O�L�O�G�I�E�S�\�X�M�E�D�I�U�S�\�C�O�N�F�I�G�
>   �M�A�N�A�G�E�R�\�S�Y�S�T�E�M�\�C�O�M�P�A�N�I�E�S�]�
>   � 1 fields in line 4: not found
>   "�N�e�x�t� �R�e�c�o�r�d�
>   �I�D�"�=�"�4�1�"� � 1 fields in line
>   5: not found

Any ideas how to approach this?

thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with dos or php?

Comment: I should be more clear.. i'm using php to parse the output file from the regedit export.

Comment: I've updated the question with the output and php code..

Comment: still, what does this have to do with DOS? I guess you mean MS DOS - but I don't think PHP runs under MS DOS. So really, I guess you mean console mode on Windows?

Comment: correct, ms dos.. i guess not much other than regedit.exe which runs in a dos batch file.

Comment: He's talking about dumping the entire registry into a text file, and then reading it with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a Perl library for this:

[Parse::Win32Registry](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parse::Win32Registry)

Making a PHP class from it shouldn't be too difficult though. There's also a PECL extension for PHP that will parse Perl code:

http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/1712

Comment: it has been fixed to key_local_machine

Answer (score 1):

Try adding /A to REGEDIT command like this to produce compatible output:

`REGEDIT /E /A "output.txt" "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System....\Company1"`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions work fine with unicode.  Are you getting a specific error message?

Answer (score 0):

From Windows XP the Regedit export is Unicode and therefore 2 bytes. You'll see this if you open up the export in notepad.  I'm not sure older versions of php are able to handle unicode files.

Is there no way you can read the specific key you need?  Through another tool etc.  That would be a much more straighforward approach.